# angular formContol.disable() is not web accessibility

Tags: angular, accessibility, angular-reactive-forms, disabled-control

angular formControl.disabled add disabled attribute to html, this attribute is not web accessibility and you need to use aria-disabled to web-accessibility. Is there a way to make formControl.disable not use disabled, but instead use aria-disabled?

angular form is not web accessibility

Comment: [MSDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-disabled) says you can just use `disabled` though.

Comment: Are you attempting to quote an error message? Your question is extremely difficult to understand as written.

Answer (score 0):

The following [documentation on `aria-disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-disabled) mentions that it will inform the user that the current state of the interactive element (e.g. button, input) is disabled.

However, `aria-disabled` doesn't perform any style changes. With the regular `disabled` attribute you'll get the correct state & visual changes (e.g. the cursor).

So, `aria-disabled` and `disabled` both inform the correct state to the user. But with `disabled` you'll have to do less yourself.